# What is the MIME type for .mobileprovision

Tags: ios, mime-types, ad-hoc-distribution

What is the correct MIME type (IIS) for a .mobileprovision file type?  Am I thinking of this the right way?  If I have to connect everybody's device to the mac dev machine to install the .mobileprovision file, it kind of defeats the purpose of the wireless ad hoc distribution method.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If there is no specific MIME-Type, you may simply use `application/octet-stream` it will work.

---

Note anyway that the AdHoc distribution method (Over The Air distribution) does not need you to provide a .mobileprovision file. At least for my case, I already did multiple OTA distributions and never provided the users a .mobileprovision file.

From Xcode, simply choose "**Build & Archive**", then once the build is archived in your "Archived Applications" in your Organizer window, simply use the "Share…" button and choose "Distribute for Enterprise".

It will create a .plist file and the .ipa file. Then put all that on your server and create a link to "itms-services://?action=download-manifest&url=http://url.to.your/app.plist" on your web page. When users will follow the link from their iPhone, iOS will prompt for OTA installation of your app.

*Note: If you want more info, sSearch the web or SO for "OTA Distribution", there are detailed articles about this including screenshots and examples.*

Comment: Thanks,I got all that taken care of, it was just that it was working fine on a device I had the .mobileprovision file installed on and it wasn't on a different device.  i think the user gave me the wrong UDID.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

*Mime(multi purpose Internet mail extensions) types*

**.mobileprovision and .ipa**

```
application/octet-stream
```

**.plist**

```
 text/plain
```

**application/octet-stream**

It is a binary file.A generic http byte streaming.Typically it will be an application or document which must be opened in application.